# Zend exclude columns without Zend Auth

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am writing a function to populate a session with user details from the db. I need to **exclude password and salt columns** so the global session doesn't get populated with them.

This can be done easily on login using:

```
$zendAuth->getResultRowObject(null, array("password", "salt"));
```

However I need to perform this elsewhere without the use of $zendAuth.

I have the following:

```
$usersTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();

$zendSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();

$zendSession->userData = $usersTable->fetchRow(
    $usersTable->select()
    ->from("users", array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status'))
    ->where("id = ?", $userInsertQuery)->setIntegrityCheck(false));
```

I had to set the integrityCheck to false as I was getting errors about not being able to join on a select statement.

There must be a simpler way to get certain column names from the db using $usersTable

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just add a method in your DbTable model or mapper class to fetch this data for you. For your current question try this:

```
$usersTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();

$zendSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
$select  = $usersTable->select();
$select->from($usersTable,array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status'))
       ->where("id = ?", $userInsertQuery);
$zendSession->userData = $usersTable->fetchRow($select);
```

Zend_Db_Select seems to think you were trying to access multiple tables because you used two different methods (*passing an object as tablename and a string as tablename*) to access the same table in the same query.

A method in your DbTable might look like:

```
public function getUserData($id)
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->from($this, array('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'status'));
        $select->where('id = ?', $id);

        $result = $this->fetchRow($select);
        return $result;
    }
```

Then in you controller:

```
$usersTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
$user = $usersTable->getUserData($userInsertQuery);
$zendSession->userData = $user;
```

after all of this you could just store the information you want using the Zend_Auth_Storage_Session a little like :

```
 if ($result->isValid()) {
     //store the username, first and last names of the user
      $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
      $storage = $auth->getStorage();
      $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(array(
                            'username', 'first_name', 'last_name'
       )));
      //or to save all except
      $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null, array('password', 'salt')); 
  }
```

Then later you can recall that information by calling :

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
       $storage = $auth->getStorage();
       $strorage->read();
```

or you can access the same information directly from Zend_Session_Namespace using the Zend_Auth namespace:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth');
$member = $session->storage; //'storage' is the default. However the namespace and key can be changed.
```